# Understand the following control cards

Tags: mainframe, dfsort, syncsort

I have the following control cards that I can't understand how to read. Could someone help me traduce what this part of a JOB is performing?

```
 OUTFIL  FNAMES=(XSCB),BLKCCT1,INCLUDE=(67,7,CH,EQ,                            
                C'XSCB   ',OR,69,7,CH,EQ,                                       
                C'XSCB   '),                                                    
   HEADER2=(22:C'XSCB    MVS USERID SYSTEM USAGE REPORT',/,                     
            01:C'GENERATED ON ',&DATE=(MD4/),70:C'PAGE',&PAGE,/,                
            01:C'          AT ',&TIME,/,X,/,                                    
            01:C'JULIAN',/,                                                     
            01:C'DATE     TIME     SYSTEM JOB      MESSAGE',/,                  
            01:C'-------- -------- ------ -------- ---------------->'),         
   TRAILER1=(X,/,01:C'RECORDS FOUND =',COUNT,/,34:C'END OF REPORT'),            
     OUTREC=(20,07,ZD,EDIT=(TTTT.TTT),X,                * JULIAN DATE           
             28,08,X,                                   * TIME                  
             11,06,X,                                   * SYSTEM                
             40,08,X,                                   * JOB OR REF            
             59,07,CHANGE=(50,C'IEF125I',C'LOGGED ON ', * MESSAGE               
                              C'IEF126I',C'LOGGED OFF'),                        
                  NOMATCH=(79,50),                                              
             132:X)
```

I understand that it searches the ID 'XSCB' in the position 67 or 69. But once it finds it, I cannot interpret what it does next.

Comment: Wow - um, it's generating a System Usage Report?

Comment: Well, looks like this 'XSCB   ' is 7 characters. So it seems withing the XSCB file, it is looking for records where 'XSCB   '  exists in position 67 or 69?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are SORT control cards. If you look at the SYSOUT for the step, and pay attention to the messages, you will be able to tell if it is DFSORT (messages prefixed by ICE) or SyncSORT (messages prefixed by WER).

Your step may be EXEC PGM=SORT or ICEMAN or something else, depends on your site.

The control cards are producing a report. You have at least one line missing from your control cards (OPTION COPY, or SORT FIELDS=COPY or a different SORT or MERGE statement). There could be any number of missing cards, and you possibly have another output from the step. Otherwise the OUTFIL INCLUDE= could perhaps be a plain INCLUDE COND=.

What does what you have shown actually do?

OUTFIL defines final processing for a particular output data set. With no name, it would be for the SORTOUT DD in your JCL.

With FNAMES=(XSCB) it is for a DD named XSCB in your JCL. For a single name specified in FNAMES, the brackets are redundant.

BLKCTT1 says "put a blank in column one to not get a page-eject from TRAILER1 output".

The INCLUDE= is as you suspect. Testing two different starting positions for the same value. If either test is true, the current record will be included in the OUTFIL group.

HEADER2 defines what appears at the top of each page.

The 01: is a column-number, and is redundant, as each line by default starts are column one.

HEADER2 can create multiple lines (as can any HEADERn or TRAILERn and BUILD (or OUTREC, but don't use it for new) on OUTFIL), each separated by "/". &DATE, &TIME and &PAGE are special, containing the obvious. &DATE can be formatted in various ways, MD4/ is MM, DD, YYYY separated by slashes.

The X is a blank, on a line of its own. You could equally see .../,/... or n/ to create n multiple blank lines.

The constants should be obvious.

TRAILER1 defines what is printed at the end of the report.

COUNT is the number of records in the OUTFIL group, here used with no formatting, but it can be formatted.

The 34: column-number means the items following will start from column 34.

The OUTREC is better spelled as BUILD. OUTREC exists elsewhere. BUILD has been around for more than 10 years, so no need to use OUTREC on OUTFIL in new code (maybe this is old anyway).

What the BUILD would do is format the current input record into what is desired for an output line on the report.

The numbers in pairs are start-position and length of fields. Where no field-type is defined, they are (treated as) character fields.

You have one field-type, ZD, which is zoned-decimal. Its length is seven, and an EDIT mask is used, four digits, full-stop (decimal-point) and then three digits.

The Xs as previously are blanks, used as separators on the report. The content of each field is described in a comment. A comment is any text after the end of a control card. A control card ends at the blank after the statement is complete, or where a there is a blank after a possible continuation (a comma or a colon are possible continuations).

132:X puts a blank in column 132, and pads any intervening columns from the last field or constant with blanks.

That leaves the CHANGE=.

CHANGE= is a very useful test-and-replace.

```
79,50,CHANGE=(50,C'IEF125I',C'LOGGED ON ', * MESSAGE               
           C'IEF126I',C'LOGGED OFF'),                        
              NOMATCH=(79,50)
```

This says "at the current column of the record being created, consider the content of the input from position 79 for a length of 50. The output length will be 50. If IEF125I, then use the constant LOGGED ON, if IEF126I use LOGGED OFF, and else (NOMATCH) use whatever is at position 79 for a length of 50 from the input.

Basically, the report is using the system log, or an extract from it, to report activity related to the Userid/Logon XSCB.